# m2eclipse: Like "mvn test" but with GUI?

Tags: eclipse, unit-testing, junit, m2eclipse

We have a multi-module Maven setup with a master pom.xml that includes all the others.  So `mvn test` from the root directory runs all our unit tests, with textual output.

I can do Run / Run As / JUnit Test to run a single test class with a graphical test runner.

Question: How do I combine the two, so that I can run all the tests that `mvn test` runs but with a graphical runner, like the one from Run / Run As / JUnit Test?

Answer (score 0):

Create an eclipse project with all your modules as Maven Dependecies and then create a JUnit [Suite](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/runners/Suite.html) which incorporates all tests. Eclipse's JUnit Runner then will execute all declared Tests if you run this suite.

Comment: Thanks, but the suite is manual whereas `mvn test` is automatic: With `mvn test` it suffices to put the class into the right directory.  So if I use this approach, I'm looking at a maintenance issue as I need to manually keep the suite and Maven in sync.

Comment: If you want to use eclipse's JUnit runner, then you need a test class or suite! So I think what you want is a JUnit suite which automatically synchronizes with your Maven project tree. But I suspect that you have to do it manually or you must write your own synchronization routine.

Comment: This is not true with recent versions of Eclipse.  Run as -> jUnit test on the project will autodiscover JUnit 4 classes.

Answer (score -1):

In Eclipse Juno, assuming your project is a Maven Project, you can just right click the project name in the Project Explorer and select Run As ... jUnit test.  Alternatively you can produce the same text output you get from `mvn test` by selecting Run As ... Maven test

Comment: This answer just repeats the question.

Comment: No it doesn't.  While the asker had figured out that they were able to run the GUI for an individual test class, my answer pointed out that they were able to do the same thing by right clicking on the PROJECT NAME ITSELF, not just the individual class's name.  Please read the answer carefully before downvoting.

Comment: Run as .... Junit test on the project does not know anything about the maven configuration. To verify use ArgLine.

Comment: If you rephrase your answer so "read the answer carefully" is not needed, I'll remove my downvote and comments.